# Python Pandas - Getting all rows where an ID (many) where the score of that ID is not equal to 1

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the issue of getting all the rows if an ID does not have a score = 1 and return all of the rows that id is associated with.

Dataframe:

```
INDEX  ORG_ID  Score
1      5467    1.0
2      5467    .897
3      8979    .50
4      8979    .60
5      1256    .50
```

Expected Outcome:

```
INDEX  ORG_ID  Score
3      8979    .50
4      8979    .60
5      1256    .50
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

I wouldn't want ORG_ID 5467 because one of the rows is = 1.0.

Thank you!

Comment: df[~df.ORG_ID.isin(df[df.Score==1].ORG_ID.unique())]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Series.ne` to get all the rows which are `!= 1`, then groupby on `ORG_ID` and get the groups where the condition is `True` for `all` the rows.

```
m = df['Score'].ne(1).groupby(df['ORG_ID']).transform('all')
df[m]

   INDEX  ORG_ID  Score
2      3    8979    0.5
3      4    8979    0.6
4      5    1256    0.5
```